# Displaying a grid {height : 10, width:10} as background with React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, grid

Good morning,

for purpose of sizing problem and element's positions on the screen between several devices, I want to display a grid as background (like a chess Grid) like this pic, for after that, displaying items like `Text and Images` on it.

[image]

The problem, is that the grid must be dynamical for each differents screen devices (like `flex:1`). That s why I don t want to use an image. Any idea about how to do it using code ? :/

Comment: Do you need it to be a fixed height/width in pixels, percentage dimensions are not good enough?

Comment: I finally used `react-native-grid-component` and set the height to `10` and the numbers of items by row with `WidthScreen / 10`. It works ! Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem and I'll explain how I would do this.

Firstly I would be using grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ if you aren't familiar.

I would set the parent's width and height to be dynamic and depend on the device.
Then set parent to `display:grid;` `grid-template-rows:repeat(#,1fr)` and `grid-template-columns:repeat(#,1fr)` where # is number of rows or columns. The fr unit basically evenly splits the available space between all of the columns/rows it needs to make. Put simply, 100px wide parent with 2 divs each with 1fr means both divs get 50px.

Put the right amount of children divs in the parent, it should auto fill the grid for you, if not then you would have to go through and put a `grid-area:rowNum/colNum/span 1/span 1;` on them.

Id give all divs in a row a class and then do `.rowOne:nth-child(even)` to style with chess pattern, so white and black.

If you needed to select a particular tile do `.rowOne:nth-child(tilenumber)` and go for your life.

Let me know if this helped or I did not understand the question at all :)

Comment: Well I m using React Native, so, nop it doesn t really helped me. :/

Comment: CSS Grid is not available in React Native

Comment: TIL rip, hope i dont have to do react native anytime soon

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [react-native-bgimage][1] which allows you to create a tiled background image, so I think this could help you do the trick. If you provide an image of 100x100 pixels with 10px tiles, I would assume the library would repeat that image for you.

Disclaimer: I have not yet tested this out!